# No entry for the Equals key in the System.Windows.Input.Key enum?

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard

I'm trying to set an `InputGesture` on a `RoutedUICommand`, hooking it up to catch when the user presses `Ctrl + =`. I'm using a `KeyGesture` object, but I can't see an entry in the `System.Windows.Input.Key` enum for the equals ('=') key.

What I was expecting was to be able to do the following:

```
ZoomIn = new RoutedUICommand("Zoom In", "ZoomIn", typeof(Window),
    new InputGestureCollection { 
        new KeyGesture(Key.Equals, ModifierKeys.Control) 
    });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Have you checked what value it returns when you do press `=`?

Comment: A very good point. *hangs head in shame*

Comment: don't forget to accept your own answer as correct :)

Comment: Yep - just got to wait for a while before it'll let me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by ChrisF, I needed to engage my brain a little. For what it's worth, the value generated when handling the `KeyDown` event is `Key.OemPlus`.

**Update:**
One consequence of this is that, if you're doing the same same as me and you're going to use the command in a menu, you'll probably want to use the overloaded constructor for `KeyGesture` that takes a 3rd parameter of `displayString`. For example:

```
new KeyGesture(Key.Equals, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+=")
```

Otherwise, you'll see the keyboard shortcut displayed as (in my case) "Ctrl+OemPlus", which isn't exactly desirable. Admittedly, the above still isn't great, but it's better than "OemPlus".

Comment: So the equals key is just a plus key supplied by an Original Equipment Manufacturer? Hmm.

Answer (score 3):

One hack is to catch the shift keydown, and if the OemPlus keydown comes before the shift keyup, you have a "OemEqual".
The code may look like this:

```
private bool shift = false;
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Key key = e.Key;
    switch (key) {
        case Key.LeftShift:  this.shift = true; break;
        case Key.RightShift: this.shift = true; break;
        case Key.C:         this.helper.Command(CMD.CLEAR); break;
        case Key.Enter:     this.helper.Command(CMD.EVAL); break;
        case Key.OemMinus:  this.helper.Operator(OP.SUB); break;
        case Key.OemPlus: 
            if (this.shift) {
                this.helper.Operator(OP.ADD);
            } else {
                this.helper.Command(CMD.EVAL);
            } break;
        case Key.OemPeriod: this.helper.Number(NumberPad.DECIMAL); break;
        case Key.D0:        this.helper.Number(NumberPad.ZERO); break;
        case Key.D1:        this.helper.Number(NumberPad.ONE); break;
        case Key.D2:        this.helper.Number(NumberPad.TWO); break;
        :
    }
}
private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Key key = e.Key;
    switch (key) {
        case Key.LeftShift: this.shift = false; break;
        case Key.RightShift: this.shift = false; break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i test it, i get `Key.Unknown` as the key code, and `PlatformKeyCode=` = `0x000000bb` (187)

Comment: Interesting. I take it you're testing this with Silverlight?

Comment: i was about to say "No", and then it dawned on me that the project i tried it in *was* silverlight... that's even stranger that they're different across wpf and silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

> No entry for the Equals key in the System.Windows.Input.Key

This isn't true.

You use `Key.OemPlus` for the `+/=` key

You use `Key.OemMinus` for the `-/_` key

This pattern stays the same for other keys that are dual use, it wouldn't make sense to have two key codes for the same key.

You use a `Key Modifier` like `Shift` to determine what the user intended.

As an example of what I mean by this, traditionally when you press `Key.OemPlus` we assume you are pressing `=`, We don't count it as `+` unless you are holding `Shift` down.